# jQuery Array Undefined Error

Tags: jquery, arrays, undefined

I have been wrecking my brains trying to figure out why I get an undefined error for the array statusIdValues when I hit the first push in the code below. Its initialised in a ready function and is pushed into when a checkbox state changes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var statusIdValues = [];

      $(':checkbox').change(function () {

      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          statusIdValues.push($(this).attr("value"));
      }
      else {
           var index= statusIdValues.indexOf($(this).attr("value"));
           if (index > -1) {
           statusIdValues.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `array.indexOf($(this).attr("value"));` What is array ?

Comment: typo, ill update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, change in the else the variable "statusIdValues" for "index", and "array" for your actual array "statusIdValues", like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var statusIdValues = [];

      $(':checkbox').change(function () {

      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          statusIdValues.push($(this).attr("value"));
      }
      else {
           var index = statusIdValues.indexOf($(this).attr("value"));
           if (index > -1) {
           statusIdValues.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thats it, would you believe I also had a second set of eyes on this we both didnt spot that typo! Thank you.

Comment: So, this is the answer?  Then why did you update your question to match this?  Is there even a question now?

Comment: I updated it because I realised there was a typo, which coincidentally was also the problem which JC also saw and fixed.